# opening a list of .csv files and do something

Tags: python, list, csv, readlines

I have a list of 25 .csv files.  I am trying to open each file, remove the first 10 lines and then have the rest of the lines merge into one file.

I have the following code:

```
Files = glob.glob("filepath-*.csv")
for file in Files:

    line = open(file, 'r')
    lines = line.readlines()[10:]
    print lines
```

however when I try to open the file it says it has no attributes to it..

How do you open a file from a list???

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.islice to write all but the first ten lines of each csv to a new file:

```
from itertools import islice

files = glob.iglob("filepath-*.csv") 
with open("joined.csv","w") as joined:
    for f in files:  
        with open(f) as temp:
            joined.writelines(islice(temp,10,None))
```

There is nothing in your own code that would throw an error however inefficient it may be bar you have assigned `line` to something else before you call readlines.